# Validation Rule for Text Field - Numbers and Decimal Points Only

Tags: validation-rule

I have a text field that should have been set up as a number field. User does not want to lose history, but needs to ensure only numbers and decimal points can be used.
Field Name = Server Version
I have used this:
NOT(ISNUMBER( Server_Version__c ))
However, because some server versions have multiple decimals, it fails in those instances. If the user inputs 7.4, for example, it works, but if the user inputs 7.6.3, it fails.

What did not work for me:
NOT(REGEX( Server_Version__c,"^[a-z A-Z]*$")),
I am not sure why this failed, but would never trigger the VR.

Open to suggestions!

Comment: The best way to tackle this would be to change the field type. I understand that the user does not want to loose the history data, in this scenario you can take a backup of the data. Change the field type and import the data back into salesforce.

Comment: I agree with you, but didn't think of the solution as you presented it. I found a formula that works perfectly for the VR so I am ok now.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT(ISBLANK(Server_Version__c)) && NOT(REGEX(Server_Version__c, "^\\d+(\\.\\d+)*$"))`

Regular expression syntax is based on [Java Platform SE 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) syntax:
`\d` stands for a digit: [0-9]
`.` means any character, so if you want to check for the literal "." you need to escape it.
`X*` means X, zero or more times
`X+` means X, one or more times

So a valid string should start for at least one digit, then it may or may not be followed by a dot followed by at least one digit.
Some valid string are:

- 5
- 2.1
- 1.13.7

Some invalid ones are:

- hello
- 5. 
- .5
- 5a
- .2.1

If the field is required, you can remove `NOT(ISBLANK(Server_Version__c)) &&`.

By the way, a numeric field will not hold "3.2.1". Salesforce would remove those dots showing "321".

Comment: Thank you - I found a simpler solution for the formula: 
NOT(ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(Server_Version__c, ".","")))
This works perfectly, so just keeping it as it.